# How make dynamic change stage name in Jenkinsfile Declarative pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I have **Jenkinsfile (Scripted Pipeline)**

```
def template1 = "spread_sshkeys"

node {
    // Clean before build
    stage('Checkout') {
        deleteDir()
        checkout scm
        sh "git submodule foreach --recursive git pull origin master";
    }
    stage("import template ${template1}") {
            script{
                sh "ls -las; cd jenkins-ci-examples; ls -las";
                jenkins_ci_examples.sub_module = load "jenkins-ci-examples/${template1}"
            }
    }
    stage("run template ${template1}") {
sh "echo ${jenkins_ci_examples.sub_module}";
    }
}
```

after want to Converting to Declarative

```
def template1 = "spread_sshkeys"

pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage ("Checkout") {
            steps {
                deleteDir()
                checkout scm
                sh "git submodule foreach --recursive git pull origin master"
            }
        }
        stage("import template ${template1}") {
            steps {
                    script {
                        sh "ls -las; cd jenkins-ci-examples; ls -las";
jenkins_ci_examples.sub_module = load "jenkins-ci-examples/${template1}"
                    }
            }
        }
        stage("run template ${template1}") {
            steps {
                sh "echo ${jenkins_ci_examples.sub_module}";
            }
        }

    }
}
```

After start Jenkins Job stop and return Error

```
WorkflowScript: 22: Expected string literal @ line 22, column 19.
               stage("import template ${template1}") {
                     ^

WorkflowScript: 30: Expected string literal @ line 30, column 19.
               stage("run template ${template1}") {
                     ^
```

Try to use

```
stage('run template ${template1}')
```

and else

```
stage('run template '+template1)
```

returned error too.

How solve this problem?

Comment: Error message implies you cannot do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create dynamic stages using sequential stages as below:

```
def template1 ="spread_sshkeys"
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Dynamic Stages') {
            
            steps {
                script {
                        stage("import template ${template1}"){
                            println("${env.STAGE_NAME}")
                        }
                         stage("run template ${template1}"){
                            println("${env.STAGE_NAME}")
                        }
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: @Nikolay Baranenko does this work for you

Comment: stage('Dynamic Stages')  - solution context stage may be empty?

Comment: Yes you can but while displaying it would show ``error`` instead of ``Dynamic stages``